# Workflow Formula using field from another object

Tags: workflow

I am trying to write a formula for below scenario

Opprtunity : Field 1

Product (Custom Object) : Field X

Field 1 updates when field X is Certain value. I have created lookup relationship between opportunity and product so that i can access the field x

Formula for criteria of workflow I am writing is 
opportunity__r.field x == "Test"

it seems not working and I don't understand why? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to trigger the workflow on the child product when the parent opportunity is changed then this will not work. The workflow rule will only fire when the child product is changed. What you could do instead is use the process builder to monitor the opportunity change and then update the child product records from there.

Comment: Hi Jenny 

I am trying to update opportunity only. Which is my parent object and I am creating workflow on Opportunity only and not produtct.

Comment: @Ricky if product is the child of opportunity then this won't work either, you could rollup the value from the child using the rollup helper http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/04/09/new-declarative-rollup-tool-release-community-powered/